# Problemas com o BufferStrategy

Tags: java, buffer

Estou recriando um código do zero, mas ao criar um BufferStrategy para poder desenhar na tela eu me deparo com o seguinte erro no console "Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer" e a minha ide diz que o problema está na linha em que eu crio o BufferStrategy dentro da verificação. (Sou relativamente novo em java e essa é minha primeira linguagem de programação). Código abaixo:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import com.flstudios.graficos.Janela;

public class Jogo extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    
    boolean estaRodando = false;
    
    Janela janela;
    Thread thread;
    
    
    public Jogo() {
        janela = new Janela(800,600);
        iniciar();
    }
    
    public synchronized void iniciar() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        estaRodando = true;
    }
    
    public synchronized void parar() {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void atualizar() {
        
        
        
        
        
        
        //System.out.println("Atualizando");
    }
    public void renderizar() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 15, 15);
        bs.show();
        
        
        
        
        
        //System.out.println("Renderizando");
    }
    
    public void run() {
    while(estaRodando == true) {
        try {
            thread.sleep(1000/60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        atualizar();
        renderizar();
        
        
        //System.out.println("Looping funciona!");
    }
    }
}
```

ps: Eu refiz o código inteiro em outro projeto e apenas em uma classe (main) e apesar de ter ficado com o mesmo código (só que em inglês) funcionou perfeitamente. A solução seria não dividir o projeto em classes? Ou talvez fazer tudo em inglês?

Comment: Só um aparte. Sua primeira linguagem de programação, e ela é orientada a objetos e você está mexendo com threads? Cada um sabe o que lhe dá motivação para programar, mas eu acho conceitos meio avançados para mexer assim numa primeira linguagem. Só uma opinião.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei do problema, só se deve mexer com `BufferStrategy` depois do `JFrame` pronto e exibido.

Então no caso acredito que faltou chamar `janela.setVisible(true)` depois da linha com o `new Janela()` e antes do `iniciar()`.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37304356/2241463

Como achei: googlando pelo texto da exception

Comment: Obrigado! Vacilo meu ^^

Comment: Por nada. Se a resposta ajudou, não esqueça de aceitá-la conforme orienta o [tour].